# Customising Richfaces skins in JBoss 7 through CSS overriding

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jboss7.x

In my richfaces 4.2.0 application, all the pages use the same template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>MY APPLICATION</title>
    <link href="/myapp/resources/css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</h:head>

<h:body class="form" >
    <div id="page">
          .....
    </div>
</h:body>
```

The file stylesheet.css is used to define some global styles as well as to override some richfaces classes. My application uses automatic skinning (*org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning = true*) as well: in brief, stylesheet.css has been designed to override everything produced by RF which was not looking as desired.

Everything worked fine under JBoss 6 because the RF styles (ECSS) were imported before stylesheet.css and hence got overridden. Under JBoss 7 (EAP 6) happens exactly the contrary, so stylesheet.css has simply no effect.

Do you know if (and how :)) I could influence this behavior?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After making some researches on the Web I found out that a good practice should be to place the custom css (using **h:outputStylesheet**) at the end of the page (or better of the template). This way they are imported at the end of the head section of the generated HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found reliably to work is to add an [**`!important`**](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/) behind each overridden RichFaces rule. But this is rather dirty.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! This is really an extreme solution! :)

Comment: @Federico - I sure hope that somebody has a better one. I'm interested myself :)

Comment: @Federico. Cool, will leave my answer here as a deterrent example and try yours, +1